# 1.1.3 - A set of discontinuity points for a function is a borel set.

Tags: measure-theory

I'm trying to solve [the exercise shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFbFG.png).

To use the hint I was thinking of the following:
$U_f=\{x\in \Omega_1:\exists_{\delta>0}\forall_{\epsilon>0} \exists_{y,z} y,z\in B_{\epsilon}(x) \land d_2(f(y),f(z))>\delta\}$

If I could write the above as something similar to $\cup^{\infty}_{1/\delta=1}\cap^{\infty}_{1/\epsilon=1/\delta} U^{\delta,\epsilon}_f=\lim \inf_{1/\delta->\infty} U_f^{\delta,\epsilon}$, by a remark I know that the lim inf of borel sets is also borel.

The problem is I'm not sure I can, nor if the equality to lim inf is correct(in a lim inf I usually have just 1 index, here I have two.)

Comment: Maybe it is best to think about this one step at a time. How can you relate $U_f$ to $U_f^\delta$ or $U^\epsilon$? That is the way I would try to approach it.

Comment: Maybe consider the function $o(x) = \limsup_{y \to x} d_2(f(x),f(y))$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set of discontinuities $D_f$ of $f$ can be written as

$$
D_{f}=\bigcup_{\substack{\delta>0,\\\delta\in\mathbb{Q}}}\bigcap_{\substack{\epsilon>0,\\\epsilon\in\mathbb{Q}}}U_f^{\delta,\epsilon},
$$
where $U_f^{\delta,\epsilon}$ is an open set.

Comment: Thanks. Much simpler. ;)

Comment: By the way, any hint on how to prove that $U^{\delta,\epsilon}_f$ is open? I thought it would be easier to write it as countable union of balls, but I don't get it.

Comment: Consider $x\in U_f^{\delta,\epsilon}$ and choose any $x_1,x_2$ s.t. $d_1(x,x_1),d_1(x,x_2)<\epsilon$, and $d_2(f(x_1),f(x_2))\ge \delta$. Then any $y$ with $d_1(x,y)<\epsilon-\max(d_1(x,x_1),d_1(x,x_2))$ is in $ U_f^{\delta,\epsilon}$.

Answer (score 0):

With apologies for using some different notations: Let $V_{\epsilon}$ be the union of all those open subsets $U$ of the source so that $\textrm{diam} f(U)\le \epsilon$, clearly an open subset. Note that $V_{\epsilon} \supset V_{\epsilon'}$ if $\epsilon > \epsilon'$. Now the points of continuity of $f$ are those that belong to $V_{\epsilon}$ for all $\epsilon >0$, so the set of continuity is

$$\cap_{\epsilon > 0} V_{\epsilon} = \cap_{n } V_{\frac{1}{n}} $$
a countable intersection of open subsets.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please explain a bit more your 1st sentence, regarding $V_{\epsilon}$? why is it clearly open?

Comment: @Klenke2ed: oh, it's a union of open subsets..

Comment: but aren't you intersecting it with a possibly closed set? The diam f(U)<=epsilon?